# How can I filter the file types I check in to TFS 2010 with Eclipse and TFS Everywhere?

Tags: eclipse, version-control

I'm using TFS for java with eclipse (running TFS Everywhere).
He wants to set a filter so that files and folders beginning with '.' won't get checked in.
How do I set it?
Is that a server or client side filter?
Do I set it in Eclipse, or in Team Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the types of files that are ignored by the TFS plug-in for Eclipse using the Team Project ignore functionality of the plug-in, which is exposed by [`.tpignore` files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfsxp/archive/2010/05/04/excluding-eclipse-project-resources-from-version-control.aspx).

If you're using the SP1 of the TFS plug-in for Eclipse (and we'd recommend upgrading, if you haven't) then you can simply right-click on the folder and select Team > Ignore.